# Word or longer expression to describe someone behaving the way they are accusing others of behaving

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests, phrase-requests

What word an/or description is used to describe someone who tell someone they're mad when they now reality as they're the ones that are being mad

I just got into an argument with my brother when he kicked the trash can and threatened violence and said I was mad – would his actions be considered as *angry* and/or *mad*, and is there a term or definition of someone who is acting or being what they themselves are doing?

Comment: Hello and welcome to EL&U. Stack Exchange aims to be a reference repository, and tags help with the identification of topics on the site. Consider changing the [tag:meaning] tag (*you* provide the word and the community helps you understand its nuances etc) to [tag:single-word-request] (you provide a description and the *community* helps pick a word that fits). The [tag:single-word-requests] tag also includes a helpful [checklist](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) to make it easier for the community to find the word that best matches what you have in mind.

Answer (score 3):

### Talk about the pot calling the kettle black.

In North American English I would use the idiom "pot calling the kettle black" to describe this situation.

The source for this idiom is the classical work Don Quixote by Cervantes.

My understanding of the idiom: the kettle is so shiny that you can see your reflection.  The pot is black and seeing its blackened reflection on the surface of the kettle, it accuses the kettle of being black.

For further reading on the idiom, plesae see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_pot_calling_the_kettle_black

If your brother were behaving this way, you might say he is being a **hypocrite** or being **hypocritical.**