# What is a word/phrase that describes someone condemning another person for something that they also do, without realizing their hypocrisy?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I'm thinking of a phrase that describes someone with a holier-than-thou attitude while being unaware (or not addressing) that they are, in fact, no better. For example, a person who vapes criticizing a smoker for ruining their lungs.
Maybe something along the lines of 'the blind leading the blind,' but with more connotations of self-righteousness and hypocrisy. Does a word/phrase like this exist?

Comment: You're in danger of getting answers to 'What is a word/phrase that describes someone condemning another person for something that they also do, revealing their hypocrisy?'which is a duplicate of say [Word or expression to describe someone  behaving the way they are accusing others of behaving3](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/461240/word-to-describe-someone-who-is-behaving-the-way-they-are-accusing-others-of-beh/461243#461243).

Answer (score 1):

The usual phrase is **the pot calling the kettle black**.

The origin is historical when pots and kettles were hung above kitchen fires. Both the kettle and the pot would become covered in soot.

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_pot_calling_the_kettle_black):

> "The pot calling the kettle black" is a proverbial idiom that may be of Spanish origin, of which English versions began to appear in the first half of the 17th century. The idiom is glossed in the original sources as being used by a person who is guilty of the very thing of which he accuses another and is thus an example of psychological projection, or hypocrisy.

Also [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pot-calling-the-kettle-black).

Comment: Though this doesn't **demand** the 'without realizing their hypocrisy' condition, I think the inclusion of 'psychological projection' (often involving being  self-deceived) rescues it from being a ballpark answer, one of 45+ hits in an in-house search for [pot] + [kettle] + [black].

Answer (score 0):

**self-ignorant** (adj.)

Under *self-* in the OED:

> 1631   R. Bolton Instr. Right Comf. Affl. Consciences 392   Never to
> bee found in the affections of a **Self-ignorant**, Selfe-confident,
> unhumbled Pharisie.
>
> 1745   J. Mason Treat. Self-knowl. i. i. 8   Condemning others for the
> very Crimes we ourselves are guilty of,..which a **self-ignorant** Man is
> very apt to do.

The only headword definition I can find is for the noun:

> **self-ignorance** (n.)
>
> Ignorance of one's own character, powers, and limitations.
> *Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary*, published 1913 by G. & C. Merriam Co. [Farlex](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Self-ignorance#:%7E:text=n.,character%2C%20powers%2C%20and%20limitations.).

*Self-ignorant* is not rare in print, for example:

> Few fall that are afraid of falling: but the **self-ignorant** and
> self-confident are careless of their way, and it is they that fall
> [Richard Baxter; *On the Mischiefs of **Self-ignorance***](https://www.google.com/books/edition/On_the_Mischiefs_of_Self_ignorance/4NMHAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=self-ignorant&pg=PA260&printsec=frontcover) (1828)

> While I am not so **self-ignorant** that I fail to realize that I
> would like to go myself, I do not quite realize that I am unlikely to
> indulge this desire without some additional reason for doing so.
> [George Ladd; *What Can I Know?*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Perspectives_on_Self_Deception/p6Psh4rXKTEC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=self-ignorant&pg=PA162&printsec=frontcover) (1914)

> The poem's title, says Simpson, cryptically restates these alternative
> possibilities: 'self-unseeing' can mean both '**self-ignorant**' and
> 'unselfconscious'... [G. Blank and M. Louis; *Influence and Resistance
> in Nineteenth-Centery English Poetry*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Influence_and_Resistance_in_Nineteenth_C/umOxCwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=The%20poem%27s%20title,%20says%20Simpson&pg=PA98&printsec=frontcover) (1994)

> To lie to oneself is to condemn oneself to **self-ignorance**, a
> blight on the inner being of a person either from an ethical or a
> psychiatric point of view. [James Drane; *Becoming a Good Doctor*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Becoming_a_Good_Doctor/ToZDHLmdQTsC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=self-ignorant%20faults&pg=PA61&printsec=frontcover)
> (1998)

> The Symposium, Sanday argues, is both a kind of warning for human
> beings about how not to live a **self-ignorant** or self-evasive life
> and a philosophical recapitulation of the Delphic command which
> reveals just how demanding it is. [James Ambury and Andy German;
> *Knowledge and Ignorance of Self in Platonic Philosophy*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Knowledge_and_Ignorance_of_Self_in_Plato/7Y92DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=self-ignorant&pg=PA13&printsec=frontcover) (2019)

Answer (score -1):

Someone who is aware of their own shortcoming might be described as *self-aware:*

> Having conscious knowledge of one's own character and feelings.
>
> > ‘we're self-aware enough to know we're making mistakes’
>
> — [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/self-aware)

[Thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/self-aware) gives the following antonyms for self-aware:

> clueless;
> oblivious;
> uninformed;
> unsophisticated;
> foolhardy;
> foolish;
> ignorant;
> thoughtless.

Of those, *clueless, oblivious* and *unsophisticated* might be the best fit, but...

It doesn’t give **self-unaware,** which I’ve used and [seen used](https://twitter.com/durendals/status/1230606366441693186) on occasion. That particular word may need to be written with the negation highlighted, *self-**un**aware,* to draw the reader to the intended meaning via *self-aware*, although most of [Twitter’s real-life examples](https://twitter.com/search?q=self-unware&src=typed_query&f=live) don’t bother.